# jQuery context menu in AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, contextmenu

Well, after hours of trying to find something out, I have to ask here and probably again (I have found similar questions, but none of them helped me).

I am trying to use custom context menu on page that is dynamicly loaded via AJAX - everything with jQuery. Problem is that the context menu just does not work on dynamicly loaded page...no menu is shown after right click at all.

I have already found out that using .live() is a solution, but still can't get it working.
Here is my last try with this [ContextMenu plugin](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/) (using just sample code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).live("load", function() {
        $('#testtt').contextMenu('testtt', {
            bindings: {
                'open': function(t) {
                    alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Open');
                },
                'email': function(t) {
                    alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Email');
                },
                'save': function(t) {
                    alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Save');
                },
                'delete': function(t) {
                    alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Delete');
                }
            }
        })
    });

</script>
<div id="testtt">test</div>
```

This is the important path that is on the page that is loaded dynamicly.

I am also using jQuery UI Sortable, but that shouldn't by problem.

Thanks for every helpful solution.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `live` is for elements that may be constructed after you call `live`, which is not very useful here because `document` only exists once at all times. In fact, without a selector `live` does not really do anything fancy anyway.

Comment: Well, have been learning with jQuery just for few last days, so I'm still noob in jQuery. As I wrote, this is just my last try, I am trying to accomplish having context menu working on AJAX loaded page. So far no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your $('#testtt').contextMenu... call to your Ajax success() method like below.  This will ensure that your context menu is hooked up AFTER your data is loaded and displayed on the screen.  It should be the last thing in your Ajax success().  Alternatively it could go in Ajax complete().

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'PATH TO URL',
    success: function(){
        $('#testtt').contextMenu('testtt', {
            bindings: {
                'open': function(t) {
                    alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Open');
                },
                'email': function(t) {
                    alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Email');
                },
                'save': function(t) {
                    alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Save');
                },
                'delete': function(t) {
                    alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Delete');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope, did not help. Behaviour is still the same :(

Comment: Well, finaly proceeded...solved out by using one of context menu plugins I have tried before and main problem was not loading of #testtt...but the div with the menu. Still, this was helpful too, wouldnt figure this out without your answer. Thanks.